# java code : distance between two points

Tags: java

I want to use the following formula to calculate distance between two points

[image]

How do put this into code to find the distance.

```
public class Point
{
    public int x; // the x coordinate
    public int y; // the y coordinate

    public Point (int x, int y)
    {
        this.x=x; 
        this.y=y;
    }

    public static double distance (Point p1, Point p2)
    {
         // to do
        return 0.0;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "("+x+","+y+")";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this

```
public static double distance (Point p1, Point p2)
{
    double dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2.0) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2.0));
    return dist;
}
```